# Electron register protocol not working

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying this:

https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/protocol/

And I get this error:

```
https://google.com/#q=standard%2Fno-callback-literal  Unexpected literal in error position of callback
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Please try to give some context to your question. Although SO is full of great programmers, I'm pretty sure most of them can't read minds :)

Comment: It is an Electron project, copy the code from the docs into index.js

Answer (score -2):

Solution is to install this so the callback can work:

https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-standard